# How do I pass my initialValues to a child component in react using Formik?

Tags: reactjs, react-props, formik

I know this question might seem basic, but I am learning react and Formik. I am trying to build a form component where the user can dynamically add new inputs if needed. This is stored in the "Names" component which will be imported into the "Survey" component.

It seems that the Names component isn't getting the values from initialValues because this is the error that I am getting.

```
./src/components/Names.js

Line 20:12:  'values' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

I have tried to pass them down as props, but it doesn't seem to be recognizing it.

The Survey Component looks like this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Formik, Field, Form, ErrorMessage, FieldArray } from 'formik';
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import Names from './Names'


const Survey = () => {
  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={{
        names: [{firstName: '', lastName: '', middleName: '', id: "" + Math.random()}]
       }}
      validationSchema={Yup.object({
        firstName: Yup.string()
          .max(15, 'Must be 15 characters or less'),

        lastName: Yup.string()
          .max(20, 'Must be 20 characters or less')
      })}
      onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {

        setTimeout(() => {
          alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
        }, 500)

      }}
    >
    {({ values, errors, isSubmitting }) => (
      <Form>
        <Names values={values}/>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </Form>
    )}

    </Formik>
  )

}



export default Survey;
```

Here is the Names component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Formik, Form, useField, FieldArray } from 'formik';
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import InputField from './InputField'

const Names = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
    <FieldArray name="names">
      {(arrayHelpers) => (
        <div>
          <button onClick={() =>
            arrayHelpers.push({
              firstName: '',
              middleName: '',
              lastName: '',
              id: "" + Math.random()
            })
          }>Add a Name</button>
//NOT BEING RECOGNIZED
          {values.names.map((name, index) => {
            return (
              <div key={name.id}>
                <InputField
                  label="First Name"
                  name={`names.${index}.firstName`}
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Enter Your First name"/>
                <InputField
                  label="Middle Name"
                  name={`names.${index}.middleName`}
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Enter Your Middle name"/>
                <InputField
                  label="Last Name"
                  name={`names.${index}.lastName`}
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Enter Your Last name"/>
                  <button onClick={() => arrayHelpers.remove(index)}>Remove name</button>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      )}
    </FieldArray>

    </>
  );
};

export default Names;
```

I have also tried passing it down as
`values.names`
from the Survey component and then in the Name component I wrote
`this.props.values.map`
but that didn't work either.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the answer.

It needed to be

```
props.values.map
```

Because I am passing it down as "props". Which is why just "values" wouldn't work.